# Set parameters of android.location.Location object from JUnit unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-location, locationmanager

I'm trying to make unit test for a function which receive android.location.Location object. But i blocked because i don't have possibility to set up parameters for Location object.

```
@Test
public void testLocation() {
    Location location = new Location("gps");
    location.setAccuracy(25F);
    location.setTime(5123L);
    System.out.println("Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
    System.out.println("Time: " + location.getTime());
}
```

Output:

```
Accuracy: 0.0
Time: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Location accuracy and time are zero but the values were set in code above.
It's not an Intrumentation test, i'm running it as simple unit test under jvm (Test Artifact: Unit Tests).

Using JUnit 4.12

Answer (score 5):

After adding @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) - it works as expected.